# C# Xamarin Forms в Visual Studio, компиляция

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Недавно начал изучать это адский комбайн и уткнулся в то, что, при компиляции кода, если студии что-то не нравится, код просто не будет скомпилирован. В этом случае тупо приходится утюжить весь код по символам в поиске ошибки, что же не так. Может есть где-то в студии настройка, чтобы она всё-таки показывала, где именно ошибка?

Comment: Вам [окно ошибок](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window) нужно? Если да, то странно что оно не появляется при компиляции (поищите его). Если нет, то опишите подробно и по шагам, что именно Вы делаете и что происходит.

Comment: Окно ошибок отображается. Там сейчас нет ошибок, только предупреждения. Ранее с этими же предупреждениями прога запускалась, так что дело не в них. Компилю в дебаге в режиме Live Player на андроид телефон. Когда студии всё нравится, на телефоне вижу прогу. Если нет - просто прекращается процесс. И никакой инфы, в чём дело

Comment: Сам с андроид через VS не работал и помочь не могу, к сожалению. Полагаю Ваш сценарий достаточно специфичный и достоин подробного описания в тексте вопроса. Еще, Вы говорили, что «... утюжили код по символам в поиске ошибки ...», если в итоге ошибку нашли, то расскажите, что именно не понравилось студии.

Comment: Пример ошибки: не в том месте поставил символ =, или указал в файле xaml метод, которого нет в файле cs. Студия просто молчит о таких нестыковках, нужно искать ошибку самому. В этом посте мой вопрос конкретно такой, как заставить студию хотя бы намекать, где ошибка

Comment: Похоже на ошибку в студии/эмуляторе. Все-таки внесите пример ошибки и описание процесса из комментариев в текст вопроса (под вопросом есть кнопка «править»)

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо включить XAML компиляцию. Это можно сделать дописав строчку
в файле AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```